# Java if...else statement not working properly

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public double transferSavingToChecking(double Tamount2)
{
    //check if enough to transfer
    if(Tamount2 > Saving_Balance)
        System.out.println("Transfer failed. You don't have enough     balance in the saving account!");
    else
        System.out.println("You have successfully transferred $" + Tamount2 + " from the saving account to the checking account");
        Saving_Balance = Saving_Balance - Tamount2;
        Checking_Balance = Checking_Balance + Tamount2;

    return Checking_Balance;
}
```

When money is transferred, the `if...else` statement runs through every time. For example, even when the `transfer > balance`, the output reflects that the transfer occurred anyways even when it says it failed.

Comment: Well...if you've got conditional behavior that belongs in those if statements, then you want to use curly braces or things like this can result.

Comment: This the way you programmed it.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: To be clear, I DO NOT want the else statement to run unless the Tamount2 is < Saving_Balance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put curly braces around the content of your if/else blocks. If/else statements are written in the following way:

```
if (condition) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

If you miss out the curly braces, only the first statement after the if/else is considered part of the if/else block.

Change your code to the following:

```
public double transferSavingToChecking(double Tamount2) {
    //check if enough to transfer
    if(Tamount2 > Saving_Balance) {
        System.out.println("Transfer failed. You don't have enough     balance in the saving account!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have successfully transferred $" +     Tamount2 + " from the saving account to the checking account");
        Saving_Balance=Saving_Balance - Tamount2;
        Checking_Balance=Checking_Balance + Tamount2;
    }
    return Checking_Balance;
}
```